# Big data and spatial regression: how to make spml more efficient in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, big-data, geographically-weighted-regression

I am running a spatial panel regression in R using `spml` from package [splm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splm/index.html). When I conduct this on about 1/200th of my data, the program executes. But when I try to do so on a third of my data, R uses up all the memory on the terminal I am working on and the program crashes. My code for specifying the spatial regression is below. How would I make this function operate efficiently enough to produce results and not crash? My terminal has 22 core, so parallel processing is likely an option - I just don't know how to perform this with spml.

````
results = spml(fm, 
                data=dtaSub,
                listw=weightsList,
                model="within", 
                effect = "twoway",
               spatial.error = "b")
```
````

Comment: How big is your data? Many spatial methods have to compute a full NxN distance matrix and so have quadratic memory costs, and you'll be off the scale pretty quickly. Have you looked at alternative methods designed for big data? Can you take random samples and pool estimates from splm?

Comment: My data consists of about 400,000 tiles (resolution: 0.01 degrees) over 12 years. I've been working with about 1/3 of this data (130,000 tiles, 12 years) and the shapefile is 185 MB. The data itself spans a large land area: each tile is in a 30 km buffer around a point of interest, but these points of interest appear across a subcontinent. I am familiar with some of the big data methods for regression, but I am here to learn if there are similar methods that can be used with splm.

Comment: Be mindful of the curse of dimensionality. Large data will tend to converge on a distribution due to size and not functional form thus, yielding erroneous correlative results. This is a fairly basic characteristic of linear regression methods and the entire point of methods such as robust regression. I echo @Spacedman recommendation regarding sub-sampling but, more due to producing a valid set of models contributing to a pooled estimate. Often with HUGE sample sizes you are facing a pseudoreplication issue so, there is good logic behind sub-sampling.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may want to consider the **parallel** option the **splm** package has. This option is embedded within the **local** option. This is what worked for me:

```
 Model_splm <- splm(fm, 
                data=dtaSub,
                listw=weightsList,
                model="within", 
                effect = "twoway",
               spatial.error = "b",
               local=list( parallel = T))
```